# install scrapy on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I'm trying to install **scrapy** on my **Ubuntu 12.10 32bits**, with **Python 2.7.3**
I followed the Ubuntu specific instructions given here : http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/ubuntu.html

All the install process seems to work fine but when i make a scrapy command here is what i get :

```
    scrapy startproject tutorial
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in 
      execute()
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 121, in execute
      cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 45, in _get_commands_dict
      cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 28, in _get_commands_from_module
      for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 19, in _iter_command_classes
      for module in walk_modules(module_name):
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 66, in walk_modules
      submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/commands/deploy.py", line 13, in 
      from w3lib.form import encode_multipart
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/w3lib/form.py", line 2, in 
      if six.PY2:
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PY2'
```

I'm an Ubutu newbie... does someone has an idea of what's going wrong ?

regards

Comment: how did you install it? `pip install Scrapy`? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/intro/install.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install Scrapy? Did you use `pip`, `easy_install` or you downloaded the source and installed it.

`pip` will install the dependencies for you, so if you installed Scrapy from the source, you should install the dependencies before installing Scrapy.

Anyway always use `pip` to install a python module.

```
pip install Scrapy
```

Comment: the Ubutu doc says to use **aptitude**... I'm going to try with pip

Comment: yes, `pip` is just for python modules. `pip` is a tool for installing and managing Python packages.

Comment: if you don't have `pip` installed, do `easy_install pip`.

Comment: i managed to install it from the download center GUI and it works :-)

Comment: Just be aware that software centre rarely has the most up to date version.  E.g. scrapy on software centre is version 0.12, most recent scrapy version is 0.19 I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but installing pip using `easy_install pip` and then installing Scrapy by `pip install Scrapy` worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it working upgrading pip, doing this

```
sudo pip install -U pip
sudo pip install Scrapy
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue back then and It was because the Ubuntu package was messing with the pip package.

I recommend you to remove scrapy packages from Ubuntu if you tried using Pip.

First remove scrapy with all local config file from ubuntu by following command :

> apt-get remove --purge python-scrapy
>
> pip uninstall scrapy

After these actions finished you can reinstall it using following commands.Now version should be 0.24.4.

1. Import the GPG key used to sign Scrapy packages into APT keyring:

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv
>   627220E7

2. Create /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list file using the following command:

> echo 'deb http://archive.scrapy.org/ubuntu scrapy main' | sudo tee
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scrapy.list

3.Update package lists and install the scrapy-0.24 package:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24

It should work :)